# Unparseable date: "NULL" with APOC.DATE.PARSE

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using `apoc` to calculate difference between two dates. It works when I supply value for `N.ID` in the `MATCH` clause. But it fails when I remove `N.ID` because I am trying to process the code for a bunch of IDs not a single one.

```
MATCH (N:PERSON)-[M:PLACED]-(K:ORDER) WHERE  K.ORDER_CODE="A23"  and N.ID=2511217
WITH N ,max(apoc.date.parse(SUBSTRING(M.ORDER_DATE,0,8),'d',"yyyymmdd")) AS initialTime,
apoc.date.parse(SUBSTRING(N.charge_DATE,0,8),'d',"yyyymmdd") AS finalTime
RETURN N.ID, finalTime - initialTime as difference ;
```

> `N.ID` difference
>   2511217      4

However, when `N.ID` is removed, I get:

```
MATCH (N:PERSON)-[M:PLACED]-(K:ORDER) WHERE  K.ORDER_CODE="A23"    
WITH N ,max(apoc.date.parse(SUBSTRING(M.ORDER_DATE,0,8),'d',"yyyymmdd")) AS initialTime,
apoc.date.parse(SUBSTRING(N.charge_DATE,0,8),'d',"yyyymmdd") AS finalTime
RETURN N.ID, finalTime - initialTime as difference ;
```

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke function `apoc.date.parse`: Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

I think its due to the aggregation function `max`.
Can you try with this query :

```
MATCH (N:PERSON)-[M:PLACED]-(K:ORDER) WHERE  K.ORDER_CODE="A23"
WITH 
    N ,
    apoc.date.parse(SUBSTRING(M.ORDER_DATE,0,8),'d',"yyyymmdd") AS initialTime,
    apoc.date.parse(SUBSTRING(N.charge_DATE,0,8),'d',"yyyymmdd") AS finalTime
WITH N, max(initialTime) AS initialTime, finalTime
RETURN N.ID, finalTime - initialTime as difference ;
```

Comment: I still get the same error - with or without MAX. When I qualify the 'Where' clause with a specific ID it works, but fails when that's removed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are multiple `PERSON` nodes placing the same `ORDER`, but some of them lack the `charge_DATE` property needed by your query.